# How to define an implicit cast permitting method calls?

Tags: c#, casting

Suppose we have a struct which permits an implicit cast to some type, say 'string', as follows.

```
public struct Foo
{
    public string Value;
    public static implicit operator string(Foo i)
    {
        return i.Value;
    }
}
```

Let `iFoo` be an instance of `Foo`. Based on this definition, an assignment with subsequent method call like

```
string Test = iFoo;
Test = Test.Trim();
```

is syntactically correct, while a contracted call like

```
string Test = iFoo.Trim();
```

is not. What is the exact reason for this? Can the desired behaviour (possibility to call methods of `string` on instances of `Foo`) be achieved - of course by means of implicit conversion alone? If not, what is the reason for the second piece of code being syntactically incorrect?

Comment: Your struct doesn't inherit from string so why do you expect it to behave as a string? It would be surprising if a cast operator would change inheritance behavior. It would only make sense to talk about casting if `Trim` was an extension method

Comment: `iFoo = iFoo.Trim()` is not syntactically correct. Did you mean `Test = Test.Trim()` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, your comment sheds some light on this.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes indeed, I changed it.

Comment: They're both syntactically correct, the error is not a syntax error.

Comment: It *was* an error, the code was different, you're/we're both right.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen and as it stands now, the question asks why something that is syntactically correct is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: So he's using the word "syntax" incorrectly. Doesn't invalidate his question though, it's not possible to do what he wants, and he calls that a syntax error.

Comment: In what sense am I using the word "syntax" incorrectly? The lower piece of code does not compile, so it cannot be syntactically correct.

Comment: It is *syntactically* correct, but it is a compiler error. The syntax dictates how you would write your code in order to do what you want, and the syntax here is right, that's how you would write your code if the type had a Trim method. However, you get a *compiler* error that is not a *syntax* error because it doesn't.

Comment: The following sentence is syntactically correct, but wrong: I am God.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for the clarification between _syntax_ error and _compiler_ error.

Comment: Syntactically incorrect: "Shop I buy went coffee to". Syntactically correct but gibberish: "Colourless green ideas sleep furiously". The former is equivalent to a syntax error, the latter to a syntactically correct piece that won't compile, while Lasse's example to something that will compile and run but give you incorrect results.

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, visit the help center for guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, method calls will be done using different rules and does not involve casting like that. You won't be able to do what you want without:

1. Implementing all the methods you need/want on top of your own type
2. Implementing all the methods you need/want as extension methods for your type

Answer (score 1):

An implicit cast allows for two things:

1. A cast.
2. That it be implicit.

Okay, that sounds a bit tautologous, but let's take those one at a time, the cast first.

Because of the cast you can do:

```
string Test = ((string)iFoo).Trim();
```

This works because the expression `((string)iFoo)` has a defined way of working (because of the cast) and when you break down the expression `((string)iFoo).Trim()` to the expressions it is made up from, all of them are syntactic and meaningful and have defined behaviour.

Now, the *implicit* part of this, is that as syntactic sugar we can leave out the `(string)` part that does this casting *in certain cases*. This is typically done because the "widening" conversion involved is so obvious that the cast would (or at least arguably could) distract the programmer more than it makes things clear to them. Hence for example the in-built implicit cast from `int` to `long`; with `long x = 3` it's absolutely clear what would happen (the `long` value `x` is now `3L`).

Likewise with `DateTime.Now.AddTicks(2)` it's pretty clear that we want the same behaviour to happen as if we called `DateTime.Now.AddTicks(2L)`. Forcing us to add an explicit cast obscures more than it makes clear.

It gets a bit less clear with `3L.CompareTo(2)`, since both `long` and `int` have `CompareTo` methods, but there isn't really any way of banning it: implicit casts work from `int` to `long`, so that's what will happen here.

With `2.CompareTo(3L)` an implicit cast is beginning to be something that would be costing more confusion that it would solve. Even looking at that example myself as the person who wrote it, I'm not sure if it means `((long)2).CompareTo(3L)` or `2.CompareTo((int)3L)`.

When we consider the impact of multiple implicit casts and to multiple types with multiple overloads, the impact in allowing an implicit cast on the left hand side of the `.` operator could quickly lead us into situations where it is extremely ambiguous as to just what implicit casts are meant to be called where.

The syntactic sugar of implicit casting will have become syntactic vinegar.

So, it makes sense that there is no implicit casting done with the `.` operator.

The code in your answer does not have a syntax error because `string Test = iFoo.Trim();` can be interpreted meaningfully by the rules of the language, but a compiler error because by the rules of the language it can only mean "call the 'Trim()' method defined on type 'Foo' or else the 'Trim(T)' extension method where 'T' is either 'Foo' or a base type of 'Foo'". There's no such method, so the syntax is correct, but the result is impossible to fulfil.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer.